# Understanding the proof of the Skorohod representation theorem

Tags: probability, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

I am trying to understand the proof of the Skorohod representation theorem in Da Prato-Zabczyk on pages 33-35 : https://books.google.com/books?id=JYiL8zz_nC8C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

I do not understand how one can use the fact that for any open set $G \subset E$ we have $\liminf \mu_n(G) > \mu(G)$ as is suggested on page 35 to prove a.s.  convergence of $X_n$ to $X$. My understanding was that $X_n \rightarrow X$ everywhere except on the measure zero set in $[0,1)$ corresponding to $F$ as defined on page 34. Am I wrong?